# How to restrict menu to popup after adding new value and Enter pressed in component Combobox vuetify

Tags: vue.js, frontend, vuetify.js

While it's working in example, I have problem in my production code. So, combobox in vuetify provide autocomplete results and functionality to add new custom variant, but when pressing Enter menu is popup. How to disable this? No code examples in google helps with it.

```
<template>
<v-combobox
  v-model="locationType"
  :items="locationTypes"
  label="Тип локации"
  :loading="locationTypesIsLoading"
  :menu-props="{ closeOnContentClick:true }"
></v-combobox>
</template>
```

Answer (score 3):

OMG I spent hours upon hours trying to figure this out too and just got it:

Add to your v-combobox/autocomplete:

```
<v-autocomplete>
...
@change="onChange()"
refs="mytable"
</v-autocomplete>
```

Then add a new method:

```
onChange() {
   this.$nextTick(() => {
   this.$refs.mytable.isMenuActive = false
   })
}
```

and that's it!!

Comment: Thanks, this had been bugging me for many, many hours too. One typo: I think you need the v-autocomplete attribute to be "ref", not "refs".